# Python: Function not changing elements in array

Tags: python, variables

I know that in Python, variables are passed by giving a copy of the reference to the object. But I do not understand why in the following piece of code I wrote, the function `Partition` does not change the elements of `arr`.

```
def Partition(arr, lo, hi):
    pivot = arr[lo]
    i = lo
    j = hi
    while(True):
        while(arr[i] < pivot): 
            i += 1
            if i == hi: break
        while(arr[j] > pivot): 
            j -= 1
            if j == lo: break

        if i >= j : break       #check if ptrs cross

        arr[i], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[i]
    #swap lo and j
    arr[lo], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[lo]
    return j

def Sort(arr, start, end):
   if (end <= start): return
   right = Partition(arr, start, end)
   Sort(arr, start, right-1)
   Sort(arr, right+1, end)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Partition` function has a logic problem.
If you follow it with a debugger, you will see it always gets the array back to its initial state before returning. The array would actually be seen as modified, the problem is that after fiddling with it for a while, it gets back to exactly how it was when entering the function.

Do you use debugging tools? If not, start doing so now.
If so, put a breakpoint on the `return j` statement, and examine the array, you will see what I mean.

You are trying to implement a *Hoare* partitioning, right?
I think you got it somewhat mixed up. The issue is because you're comparing against the pivot before the first loop iteration, you end up comparing the elements you just swapped again.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug:

```
Assume arr = [1,3,4,7,5,8], lo=3, hi=6
def Partition(arr, lo, hi):
    pivot = arr[lo]  <- this is arr[3] = 7   
    i = lo           <- i = 3 
    j = hi
    while(True):
        while(arr[i] < pivot): <- arr[3] = 7 so condition fails hence no swap
```